# When aluminium is ignited in atmosphere, will it form only aluminium oxide or also aluminium nitride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity

We know when lithium is burnt in air, it forms lithium nitride and lithium oxide. I am wondering if this applies to aluminium (other metals) also?

Comment: Magnesium also forms the nitride as well as the oxide when burning in air.

Answer (score 3):

According to the paper by Gromov and Vereshchagin [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jeurceramsoc.2003.09.020)], it is indeed formed when burning aluminium, but you could have predicted this simply by considering the standard enthalpy of formation of aluminium oxide $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ (\ce{Al2O3}) = \pu{−1675.7 kJ/mol}$ which will be liberated upon ignition and this energy helps in breaking the strong nitrogen-nitrogen triple bond (bond energy is $\pu{−945 kJ/mol})$ and finally this would form aluminium nitride, which also produces some energy (standard enthalpy of formation is $\pu{−318 kJ/mol}),$ but the combustion here is not a simple one it requires high temperature as mentioned in the paper, I think this is to sublimate $\ce{Al2O}$ which will react with nitrogen and give rise to aluminium nitride.

[As HYDR0GEN stated](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/125640), this combustion isn't simple like throwing a match on aluminium sheet, it needs high temperature. According to the work by Trunov et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1002/prep.200400083), p. 38], as the size of aluminium particles decrease the needed temperature for combustion decreases and that's why researchers who wrote the paper used superfine aluminium powder:

> [image]
>   **Figure 5**. Experimentally determined temperatures of aluminum
>   ignition as a function of the used sample size.

#### References

1. Gromov, A.; Vereshchagin, V. Study of Aluminum Nitride Formation by Superfine Aluminum Powder Combustion in Air. *Journal of the European Ceramic Society* **2004**, 24 (9), 2879–2884. DOI: [10.1016/j.jeurceramsoc.2003.09.020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jeurceramsoc.2003.09.020). ([PDF](http://portal.tpu.ru/departments/kafedra/tsnm/sotr1/Tab/JECerS%202004.pdf))
2. Trunov, M. A.; Schoenitz, M.; Dreizin, E. L. Ignition of Aluminum Powders Under Different Experimental Conditions. *Propellants, Explosives, Pyrotechnics* **2005**, 30 (1), 36–43. DOI: [10.1002/prep.200400083](https://doi.org/10.1002/prep.200400083).

Comment: When citing third-party resources, make sure to provide a *complete human-readable reference* and not just "*this link*" to make your post robust against link rot. Also, always cite *the original publication*, not [a reproduced rip-off of a questionable quality](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/gnition-temperatures-of-different-samples-of-aluminium-samples-reproduced-from-Trunov-et_fig3_240497487) where there is typo in the axis name ("Diamter") and illiterate numbers formatting. I took a liberty to replace the illustration with with the one from original paper.

Comment: @andselisk thanks for help, it's my first answer

Answer (score 2):

When the aluminum [powder] is ignited, it will cause a reaction between the aluminum and oxygen in the atmosphere. The required temperature for the aluminum oxide to be formed is almost 3000+ °C.

$$\ce{4 Al + 3 O2 -> 2 Al2O3}$$

In addition, aluminum nitride can't be formed when the aluminum powder is ignited in atmosphere, because the aluminum nitride starts to decompose into aluminum and $\ce{N2}$ at a high temperature under atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Aluminium needs high temperature to be ignited but that's why the researchers who wrote the paper used ultra fine powder of aluminium to be ignited easily . See this link :https://www.researchgate.net/figure/gnition-temperatures-of-different-samples-of-aluminium-samples-reproduced-from-Trunov-et_fig3_240497487